# Problems with apache MAMP 3 and Yosemite

Tags: apache, mamp, osx-yosemite

I've just installed the new Mac's operative system  (Yosemite) but now I have problems to set up apache with MAMP Version 3.0.6.

Someone know if there is a conflict with MAMP and Yosemita? How can I solve this problem because I don't want to install other server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just upgraded to Yosemite as well and MAMP SQL/Apache servers wouldn't start. Installed MAMP 3.0.7.1 and the servers start now. Upgrade MAMP and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whats up with mampp, but xampp has come up with an update.. [Try the new version of xampp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Mac%20OS%20X/1.8.3/xampp-osx-1.8.3-5-installer.dmg/download)..

Answer (score 0):

Just a file to rename

find **Applications/MAMP/bin/apache2/bin/envvars** and rename it **_envvars**, restart mamp and it should work.

source : [Résolution problème MAMP sous Yosmite](https://www.bennetonable.com/blog/astuces/comment-faire-fonctionner-mamp-sous-os-x-yosmite)