# Mamp mysql server does not start on Yosemite ios8

Tags: mamp, osx-yosemite

this is a follow up of this issue:
[Problems with apache MAMP 3 and Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437932/problems-with-apache-mamp-3-and-yosemite/26443324?noredirect=1#comment41530179_26443324)

I have followed the recommendation (upgrading Mamp to the latest version) but the Mysql server still does not start: I am using default ports 8888 and 8889. When setting a different port (e.g., 80) both servers do not run...XAMP works fine instead.

Comment: ok solved by following the last answer to this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333173/mysql-with-mamp-does-not-work-with-osx-yosemite-10-10

The file is located in: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Change Listen 80 to Listen 8080

Restart your MAC, and try to launch again MAMP Services.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem running MAMP, I found that updating the **envvars_** file under MAMP/Library/bin to **_envvars** and then changing the Apache Port to **8888** and the MySQL Port to **3306** got it working for me.

I hope this helps!

Comment: it did not work for me: I guess that was a temporary solution for ios8 beta version (the stable version was released this week)

Comment: Do you mean envvars_? There is no envvars file in my installation.

Comment: Apologies, yup the envvars_ file